Question about Refresh Token expired in Google Authentication
My question is, when it's close to expiry refresh token, will I have to log in again? Example: email and password or is there another method to get another refresh token with just the client ID and client secret?
I need to resolve my issue as I'm afraid that my refresh token has expired and my client needs to log in again; I wish it wasn't like this.

Refresh tokens are long lived. They are designed to allow you to request a new access token.  By design they do not expire except under some very specific instances.
See expiration for a full list.
The most common are

You are using a gmail scope and the user changes their password.
The user has authorized your application 100 times and your not storing the newest refresh token and the oldest one expires
Your app is still in testing in which case the refresh token will expire after seven days.
the user revoked your access via their google account

While your application should prompt the user to reauthorize the application in the event the refresh token no longer works.  Its really not something that should happen often.
